# Regular expression to remove fancy apostrophe

Tags: regex

I need to send SMS to my subscribers through the API, the API doesn't support fancy apostrophe, so i would like to remove that from the message before send it to the user. So i'm looking for a regular expression that should remove the fancy apostrophe and any other unsupported characters, at the same time message can have special characters.

Comment: What is a "fancy apostrophe" and what are those "other unsupported characters"?

Comment: What all are the unsupported characters?

Comment: Here i mean that, the special characters that doesn't supported in the SMS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `\u` to allow any unicode character. If you have a limited set of unsupported characters that can be listed, then you can use character class negation by enclosing the unsupported characters in `[^` and `]`.

Comment: hey Naveed, it's somewhat useful, Thanks!